# Jquery file upload php

Tags: php, jquery, file, uploader

I got an problem with my file uploader it gives me an SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ...
I dont know where it is coming from and i have been looking for a day now but cant seem to find an answer can someone give me some advice. (some photo's do upload and when it gives that error it only doesnt make a thumbnail hope that helps. 
i think the error is somewhere down here.
thanks in advanced

```
<?php
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Class 8.2.3
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

class UploadHandler
{
protected $options;

// PHP File Upload error message codes:
// http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
protected $error_messages = array(
    1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini',
    2 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form',
    3 => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded',
    4 => 'No file was uploaded',
    6 => 'Missing a temporary folder',
    7 => 'Failed to write file to disk',
    8 => 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload',
    'post_max_size' => 'The uploaded file exceeds the post_max_size directive in php.ini',
    'max_file_size' => 'File is too big',
    'min_file_size' => 'File is too small',
    'accept_file_types' => 'Filetype not allowed',
    'max_number_of_files' => 'Maximum number of files exceeded',
    'max_width' => 'Image exceeds maximum width',
    'min_width' => 'Image requires a minimum width',
    'max_height' => 'Image exceeds maximum height',
    'min_height' => 'Image requires a minimum height',
    'abort' => 'File upload aborted',
    'image_resize' => 'Failed to resize image'
);

protected $image_objects = array();

function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
    $this->response = array();
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/index.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'&',
        'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/uploaddir/',
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/uploaddir/',
        //'user_dirs' => false,
        'user_dirs' => true,
        'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
        'param_name' => 'files',
        // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
        // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
        //'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
        'delete_type' => 'POST',
        'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
        'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
        'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
            'OPTIONS',
            'HEAD',
            'GET',
            'POST',
            'PUT',
            'PATCH',
            'DELETE'
        ),
        'access_control_allow_headers' => array(
            'Content-Type',
            'Content-Range',
            'Content-Disposition'
        ),
        // Enable to provide file downloads via GET requests to the PHP script:
        //     1. Set to 1 to download files via readfile method through PHP
        //     2. Set to 2 to send a X-Sendfile header for lighttpd/Apache
        //     3. Set to 3 to send a X-Accel-Redirect header for nginx
        // If set to 2 or 3, adjust the upload_url option to the base path of
        // the redirect parameter, e.g. '/files/'.
        'download_via_php' => false,
        // Read files in chunks to avoid memory limits when download_via_php
        // is enabled, set to 0 to disable chunked reading of files:
        'readfile_chunk_size' => 100 * 1024 * 1024, // 10 MiB
        // Defines which files can be displayed inline when downloaded:
        'inline_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
        // Defines which files (based on their names) are accepted for upload:
        'accept_file_types' => '/.+$/i',
        // The php.ini settings upload_max_filesize and post_max_size
        // take precedence over the following max_file_size setting:
        'max_file_size' => null,
        'min_file_size' => 1,
        // The maximum number of files for the upload directory:
        'max_number_of_files' => null,
        // Defines which files are handled as image files:
        'image_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
        // Use exif_imagetype on all files to correct file extensions:
        'correct_image_extensions' => false,
        // Image resolution restrictions:
        'max_width' => null,
        'max_height' => null,
        'min_width' => 1,
        'min_height' => 1,
        // Set the following option to false to enable resumable uploads:
        'discard_aborted_uploads' => true,
        // Set to 0 to use the GD library to scale and orient images,
        // set to 1 to use imagick (if installed, falls back to GD),
        // set to 2 to use the ImageMagick convert binary directly:
        'image_library' => 1,
        // Uncomment the following to define an array of resource limits
        // for imagick:
        /*
        'imagick_resource_limits' => array(
            imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP => 32,
            imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY => 32
        ),
        */
        // Command or path for to the ImageMagick convert binary:
        'convert_bin' => 'convert',
        // Uncomment the following to add parameters in front of each
        // ImageMagick convert call (the limit constraints seem only
        // to have an effect if put in front):
        /*
        'convert_params' => '-limit memory 32MiB -limit map 32MiB',
        */
        // Command or path for to the ImageMagick identify binary:
        'identify_bin' => 'identify',
        'image_versions' => array(
            // The empty image version key defines options for the original image:
            '' => array(
                // Automatically rotate images based on EXIF meta data:
                'auto_orient' => false
            ),
            // Uncomment the following to create medium sized images:

            'medium' => array(
                'max_width' => 800,
                'max_height' => 600
            ),

            'thumbnail' => array(
                // Uncomment the following to use a defined directory for the thumbnails
                // instead of a subdirectory based on the version identifier.
                // Make sure that this directory doesn't allow execution of files if you
                // don't pose any restrictions on the type of uploaded files, e.g. by
                // copying the .htaccess file from the files directory for Apache:
                //'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/medium/',
                //'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/medium/',
                // Uncomment the following to force the max
                // dimensions and e.g. create square thumbnails:
                'crop' => true,
                'max_width' => 800,
                'max_height' => 600
            )
        ),
        'print_response' => true
    );
    if ($options) {
        $this->options = $options + $this->options;
    }
    if ($error_messages) {
        $this->error_messages = $error_messages + $this->error_messages;
    }
    if ($initialize) {
        $this->initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code formatting has errors.
On topic, what is the exact error message? I.e. in which line does the error occur?

Comment: it doenst say what place the error stands its inside file uploader here is the link mozzilla says this : http://prntscr.com/9c5mc4 chrome says this: http://prntscr.com/9c5n0x hope that helps thats why i have so much trouble finding it

Answer (score 0):

Where is the error coming from. Did you check your php logs.
1. This by default will be in the php error logs.
2. Tail the logs and run the call again, you should get the line number and shoot that bugger.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This error means that in `ajax` response we get line with wrong **JSON** syntax, i.e. some `'<'`.

To be sure try this: in `javascript` delete `dataType:'json'` and in the function `success` add something like this (don't forget press `ctrl+shift+j` if you use google Chrome to see result of `console.log()`):

```
success: function(data){ 
    console.log(data); 
    // alert(data); 
}
```